# How difference between of and ‘s?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

For example -Of uses with...
‘S uses with... 
I thought ‘s uses with only abstract noun ,but on my test, the right answer  said  Should it be the surface of rock?? May you guys explain me about this? Thanks

Comment: I’m sure this has been asked before, but I can’t quickly find a good duplicate. Try searching our site in the meantime.

Comment: You need to have a pronoun: *surface of **[a / the]** rock*.